# Trouble trying to pass a structure as Object to method that iterates fields and values

Tags: c#

After gratefully borrowing from various other posts, I got this to work fine:

```
public string ShowCandle01(ref TYPE_Candle01 Candle)
{
    string S = "";
    foreach (var field in typeof(TYPE_Candle01).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance |
                BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        S = S + field.Name + ": " + field.GetValue(Candle).ToString() + "\n";
    }
    return S;
}
```

But what I really want is a method that will iterate for an instance of any structure, without explicitly knowing its name, like:

public string ShowAnyStruct(ref Object Whatever)

and I can't seem to do it.  Thanks in advance for your advanced wisdom!

Comment: Why are you using `ref` here? Also, when you say struct, do you mean an actual `struct` or any object?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is a generic method:

```
public string ShowAnyStruct<TStruct>(TStruct val) where TStruct: struct
{
    string s = "";
    foreach (var field in typeof(TStruct).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                     BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                     BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        s += field.Name + ": " + field.GetValue(Candle).ToString() + "\n";
    }
    return s;
}
```

Of course, there's not really any reason to restrict this to structs, so you can also use this with reference types if you remove the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
whatever.GetType().GetFields ....
```

---

```
public static string ShowFields(object whatever)
{
    string S = "";
    foreach(var field in whatever.GetType().GetFields(
        BindingFlags.Instance |
        BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        S = S + field.Name + ": " + field.GetValue(whatever).ToString() + "\n";
    }
    return S;
}
```

Comment: Using of `object` will also box `struct` and this is not really good performance-wise... (I didn't downvoted though)

Comment: @Fabjan Why would that matter?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Why box `struct` to `object` when there's no need for that ?

Comment: @Fabjan I doubt if boxing makes any real performance difference if reflection is used anyway.

Comment: @AlexD You've a point with that but still why boxing `struct` when there's no need for that. It doesn't make much sense (at least to me) in the first place...

Comment: @Fabjan Well, one advantage could be that the same function works for all `class`es and `struct`s, without a need to instantiate different generic functions for different argument types.